# How to calculate Protocol revenue and Supply Side revenue for Polkadot?

Tags: substrate, polkadot

I want to calculate the protocol revenue and supply-side revenue without using the TheGraph subgraph.

The problem with TheGraph is that it requires a smart contract address and all I have is an Ethereum wallet with zero balance.

I also tried to explore the [supported tools](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-data) listed on Polkadot's website but none could help me figure out how to calculate the revenue.

I am unsure how scanning a whole substrate-based chain can help me deduce the revenue generated from protocol and from fees (assuming the supply-side revenue means transaction fees only).